# Cloudfront is redirecting to our website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, puma

As of this morning, after years of working properly, our cloudfront account has been redirecting (301) to our website for assets rather than serving them up itself.  Any ideas how to revert this?

Last night I switched us from using Passenger to Puma as our web server, and as part of this, I had changed `config.serve_static_files = true` in production.rb.  However, even when I revert to `config.serve_static_files = false`, the cloudfront urls are still redirecting to our home website.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I believe that cloudfront would only emit a redirect if its request to the origin also resulted in a redirect - I would start by looking for those requests in whatever logs you have available on the server that is running puma.

Comment: @FrederickCheung could you clarify what you mean by "if its request to the origin also resulted in a redirect"?  Are you saying that somehow our server running puma is redirecting cloudfront requests to itself?  Is there something specific I should look for in our large log files?

Comment: When a browser make a request to cloudfront, cloudfront requests the relevant asset from your server. It sounds like that request is resulting in a redirect rather than the asset. I would be looking at any requests to an asset that results in a redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation, the cause of the problem was as follows:

1. Nginx apparently serves `public/` files from http even if there is a 301 redirect from http to https
2. Puma uses rack to serve `public/` files and it will return a 301 redirect to https if a public file is requested from http
3. If Cloudfront receives a 301 redirect from the server it routes to (http in this case), it just forwards a 301 redirect to the user, so they are permanently redirected to the https of the website, rather than to cloudfront to receive their files.
4. The configuration setting that fixed this was changing our cloudfront origin to 'Match Viewer' rather than to be 'Http only' as it was originally.  We then had to wait for people's cache's to clear since it had been a permanent redirect (301).

As a side note, I don't think Cloudfront should forward a 301 redirect to clients.  That seems non-ideal to me.